# CMake error with QT6, file does not exist

Tags: qt, cmake, chess

I'm trying to run cutechess cli on my computer and am running into problems that I dont understand. I've followed all the instructions [here](https://github.com/cutechess/cutechess/wiki/Building-from-source) and in the README and they do not work. cutechess cli asks for qt5 but I was only able to install qt6, which is supposed to still be compatible. I've added C:\Qt\6.4.1\mingw_64\lib\cmake\Qt6 as CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in my system variables and receive the following error.

`

```
>cmake ..
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.22000.
-- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC
-- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC - Success
CMake Error at C:/Qt/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake:14 (message):
  The imported target "Qt5::Core" references the file

     "C:/Qt/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/lib/Qt5Core.lib"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "C:/Qt/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Qt/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake:50 (_qt5_Core_check_file_exists)
  C:/Qt/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake:207 (_populate_Core_target_properties)
  C:/Qt/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:33 (find_package)
```

`

The file "C:/Qt/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/lib/Qt5Core.lib" exists on my computer, but it is a .prl file instead of a .lib. All of the files in the \qt5_design_studio_reduced_version\lib folder are .prl.

I installed QT6, added the Qt6 folder to path, and received an error saying that there are missing files.

Comment: But the error message tells that it expects `Qt5::Core` and not `Qt6::Core`. You should either install Qt5 or modify CMake scripts to search for Qt6 stuff.

Comment: Looks like `find_package(Qt6 ...)` did not work: https://github.com/cutechess/cutechess/blob/15b53791ea501589886660992bf43c399bcf9133/CMakeLists.txt#L31 Run the cmake configuration step with the `--debug-find` option to get additional info. Maybe the version of the installed qt6 is considered to be incompatible with the configuration you're using to set up your own project.

Comment: The installation of Qt6 I got is supposed to be Qt5 compatible. I've just realized that when it is looking for "C:/Qt/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/lib/Qt5Core.lib", it cant find it. This file exists, but it is a .prl instead of a .lib. Why has this happened, and is there a way for me to fix it?

Comment: Also I would much prefer to install Qt5 but I do not see anywhere that it is available. The Qt installer only allows newer versions that are supposed to include Qt5 compatibility.